# Asymptotic worst-case running time. Need some clarification

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

For the pseudocode below for the `mystery(n)` function below, find tight upper and lower bounds in its asymptotic worst-case running time `f(n)`. That is, find `g(n)` such that `f(n)` ∈ Θ`(g(n))`. (assuming that n is a positive integer)

```
Mystery (n ){                  
 c ←1                          | (constant)
 for i ←1 to n                 | n
   do for j ←i to n            | j
     do for k ← n down to n/2  | n/2
       do c ← c + 1            | (constant)
 print c                       | (constant)
}
```

Total time: (n/2)nj  (not sure on this)

The time tags on the side are what I figured out thus far. It seems for this problem that there is no difference between best and worst case run times? Additionally, how can I find a  tight upper and lower bounds for this method? Any advice would be great. Or resources where I could do some reading as my textbook is very vague on the topic.

Comment: Try writing this out as a sum of operations over just the outer loop  `(n^2/2 + (n-1)*n/2 + ...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`j` should not be in your formula since `j` is a function of `n` as well.

Whenever you have a loop that depends on the outer loop variable, I find it easiest to look at the summation formula to find the complexity.

So the outer loop definitely runs `n` times, and the inner most loop definitely runs `n/2` times, but in general `n/2 ∈ O(n)`.

So let's look at the middle loop.

The middle loop runs `(n-1)` times on the first iteration, followed by `(n-2)` times on the second iteration, all the way down to `(n-n)` which is equal to 0 times. You can rearrange these terms to simply be the sum of 0 to n. We know that this summation is equal to `n(n+1)/2`.

Since this formula represents the combination of the outer and middle loop, you can simply multiply the innermost loop to get your final formula of `n(n+1)n/(2*2) == n^2(n+1)/4`.

One conceptual thing that you should realize is that since `c` is simply a counter, and it is incremented on every iteration, `c` can be thought of as a direct representation of the runtime complexity of this algorithm.

You can verify this result by computing `c`. Here's an example program written in C to demonstrate this algorithm:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int c = 0;
  int n = 10;
  if (argc > 1) {
    n = atoi(argv[1]);
  }
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    for (int j = i; j <= n; ++j) {
      /* Note that I've changed k to run from 0 to n/2 instead of n
         down to n/2, but this doesn't change the result. */
      for (int k = 0; k < n/2; ++k) {
        ++c;
      }
    }
  }
  printf("c == %d; n^2(n+1)/4 == %d\n", c, n*n*(n+1)/4);
}
```

Here's the output from the above program for the inputs 2, 4, 8, 32, and 64:

```
c == 3; n^2(n+1)/4 == 3
c == 20; n^2(n+1)/4 == 20
c == 144; n^2(n+1)/4 == 144
c == 8448; n^2(n+1)/4 == 8448
c == 66560; n^2(n+1)/4 == 66560
```

Comment: This was extremely helpful! Thank you! I do have one question as it relates to your answer though. To put this in terms of uppercase-theta notation with tight upper and lower bounds I would simply use the most significant term of the resulting formula correct? Such that n^3 * n^2 would be n^3 as it would be the most significant over a large enough data set.

Comment: Yes, that is true as long as you mean (n^3 + n^2) and not (n^3 * n^2). I'll assume that was a typo, but just in case (n^3 * n^2) would be n^5.

Comment: Yes, I had written it incorrectly. After simplifying the resulting formula you are left with n^3 as your most significant term.

Answer (score 1):

```
Mystery (n ){                  
 c ←1                          | (constant)
 for i ←1 to n                 | n
   do for j ←i to n            | j
     do for k ← n down to n/2  | n/2
       do c ← c + 1            | (constant)
 print c                       | (constant)
}
```

You are correct about the outer loop running `n` times. However, the next loop will run n times for i=1, n-1 times for i=2, ..., 2 times for i=n-1, and once for i=n. On average, the `j` loop will run `n/2` times, so this middle loop is also considered to be an O(n) loop. This gives a total runtime complexity of O(n^3) when you combine all three nested loops.